# How to see if form has been filled out in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have functions in my userinfo model and employer model to see if their respective forms have been filled out.
Right now, my userinfo model looks like this:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
    end

end
```

And the emloyer model looks like this:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && company? && position? && number? && email?
    end
end
```

The navbar in my layout/application.html.erb where the navbar code goes is this:

```
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%if current_user.employer(&:info_complete?) %>      
                <li><p>Employer form has been filled out</p></li>
            <%elsif current_user.userinfo(&:info_complete?) %>
                <li><p>Userinfo form has been filled out</p></li>
            <%else%>  
                <li><p>Nothing has been filled out</p></li>
            <%end%>  
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>              
        <% else %>  
            <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>                  
        <% end %>
```

As you can see, this is just for testing. I display a sentence to see if my logic works.

Then the userinfo/new form is this:
[image]
And the employer/new form is this:[image]

As you can see in both the form pictures, in the navbar, it says the form has been filled out when the user just gets there. No information has been entered. Why does it pass "true" to the "info_complete?" functions in my models even though no data has been entered yet?

Comment: Why are you doing current_user.employer(&:info_complete?)  instead of current_user.employer.info_complete?

Comment: If I do .info_complete?, I get the following error: "undefined method `info_complete?' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: you should validate on the @employer and @info created in the `new` action in their controllers. Also check this for Validations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: @MahmoudSayed Can you please explain it a little bit more? How can I validate them and when would I use them?

Comment: these validations happen before saving your instance (employer for example). you POST the form fields to the `create` action and then do `employer.save` if the validations were successful the recored will be saved to database. you can do this in your `create` action `if employer.save then do something else render :new end` this should take you back to the form field with the same data, and you can show the errors of this form. I suggest to read the link I posted in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

here is your models..

user_info.rb

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major
end
```

employer.rb

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :name, :company, :position, :number, :email
end
```

**Controllers.**

employers_controller.rb

```
Class EmployersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @employer = Employer.new
  end

  def create
    @employer = Employer.new(valid_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employer.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def valid_params
    params.require(:employer).permit(:name, :company, :position, :number, :email)
  end
end
```

**views.**
employers/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

employers/_form.html.erb

```
<% if @employers.errors.any %>
  <% @employers.full_messages.each do |m| %>
    <p><%= m %></p> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

do the same for the user_info..